# Why are pages not redirecting in production when checking user agent in ActionExecuting()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

In my MVC3 application, I added the following in my controller base class' `OnActionExecuting()` method:

```
            int pageNumber = 0;
            // deny crawl for bots on pages 
            if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("pageNumber"))
            {
                pageNumber = Convert.ToInt16(filterContext.ActionParameters["pageNumber"]);


                if ((Request.UserAgent.Contains("msnbot") |
                    Request.UserAgent.Contains("googlebot")) && pageNumber > 2)
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 410;
                    Response.Status = "410 Gone";

                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("NoCrawlerMessage", "Home"));
                }
            }
```

During debugging, when I change my browser's user agent to include "googlebot" or "msnbot" the page redirects just fine.

However, when I put this into production and retry, there is no change at all - the requested page loads, which it shouldn't.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Can you log and show us the value of `Request.UserAgent` when run on the production server?

Comment: I used the Chrome UA Spoofer to change the user agent name to googlebot and msnbot.  That value is reflected from @Request.UserAgent that I placed on the view.